# Bash+Expect script not running properly in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, expect

I have a bash script that is supposed to run periodically. the script should connect to a remote SFTP server and get a file from there.
Since this is a SFTP server I had to use expect with the bash script. 
the script runs well when I run it manually but fails when running via crontab.
the problematic function is the `get_JSON_file()`
please advise...

this is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

export xxxxx
export xxxxx
export PATH=xxxxx

check_if_file_is_open(){
while :
do
    if ! [[ `lsof | grep file.txt` ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
}


get_JSON_file(){
/usr/bin/expect -f <(cat << EOF
spawn sftp -P port user@ip
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
expect "$ "
send "get path/to/file/file.json\r"
send "exit\r"
interact
EOF
)
}


get_JSON_file
check_if_file_is_open
cp file.txt /path/to/destination/folder
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expect script does not work under crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7494115/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a function within a shell script, no parentheses should be used.

Your code then becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

export xxxxx
export xxxxx
export PATH=xxxxx

function check_if_file_is_open(){
while :
do
    if ! [[ `lsof | grep file.txt` ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
}


function get_JSON_file(){
/usr/bin/expect -f <(cat << EOF
spawn sftp -P port user@ip
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
expect "$ "
send "get path/to/file/file.json\r"
send "exit\r"
interact
EOF
)
}


get_JSON_file
check_if_file_is_open
cp file.txt /path/to/destination/folder
```

Comment: This is an important fix, but does nothing to address the various other flaws and inefficiencies in the OP's script.

Comment: I don't have parentheses, when i call the function. I added it by mistake here))
the main issue is that the sftp commands are not being executed (or being executed not properly)

Comment: Oops, sorry. That was the one obvious mistake I saw. 
I'm no expert on using the sftp tool, since I mostly fetch files using cURL or wget (well maybe also scp/rsync). This can be automated pretty easily and can omit a -send/expect/interact- construction.

Answer (score 4):

Expect's `interact` works only when *stdin* is on a tty/pty but cron job is not running on tty/pty. So replace `interact` with `expect eof` (or `expect -timeout 12345 eof` if necessary).

Comment: SEE ALSO: [Expect script works while invoking individually but not as a Salt State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698791/)

Answer (score 2):

That's a very awkward way to pass expect commands to the expect interpreter. Use a (quoted) heredoc instead, and you would drop the `-f` option for expect

```
get_JSON_file(){
    /usr/bin/expect <<'EOF'
        spawn sftp -P port user@ip
        expect "Password:"
        send "password\r"
        expect "$ "
        send "get path/to/file/file.json\r"
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
EOF
}
```

The most important tip for debugging expect scripts is to invoke expect's debug output. While you're working out the kinks, use

```
expect -d <<'EOF'
```

and in the crontab, you'd want to redirect stderr to stdout so you get the debugging output

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new script with screen command and add it in crontab

```
new_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd script_path
screen -dm -S screen_name ./your_script.sh
```